# Single word to denote 'a fat stomach'

Tags: single-word-requests

Can you suggest a single word (a noun) that denotes ' a fat stomach on a man'

Comment: How about 'paunch'?

Comment: Some men have a six-pack, some have a whole keg.

Answer (score 2):

How about **potbelly**? From M-W:

> **[potbelly](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/potbellyhttps://)**: an enlarged, swollen, or protruding abdomen

Example: His **potbelly** stuck out so far it made we wonder why he didn't fall over.

Answer (score -1):

How about **Foodbaby** ? 
Modern slang.
It doesn't pertain to only men though, although it's certainly used for all genders.
https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=food%20baby